# Applying 2to3 in PyDev project in Eclipse does not affect any changes to files

Tags: python, pydev, python-2to3

I opened a Python 2 project in PyDev on Eclipse with a Python3 interpreter installed, so I get errors in certain places.

The project's context menu has a PyDev -> "Apply 2to3" option. When I select it, I see `diff` output in my console but the `.py` files in the project are not changed. I don't see any obvious way to apply the `diff` output to make those changes.

Shouldn't "Apply 2to3" perform changes to the files and leave the project ready to compile under Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enter the parameters for 2to3 to do that...

I just saw that the dialog is currently horrible (it doesn't show the full text -- back then the text from `2to3` was probably small, but now that it's big it doesn't fit on the dialog space very well and the content is cropped to what's visible -- just fixed it: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/fb0aa9d28c15e7deeb3aa229b0ad66146802d9e4).

Now, to answer your question, at the dialog that opens you need to pass `-w` to write the files creating a backup file or `-w -n` if you want to write the files but don't want to keep backup files -- which I recommend if your source code is already under source control ;)

Comment: Thanks! It might be interesting to create a dialog box with those options as defaults.